# issues with php mail function, not receiving email, zen_mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

Reference: https://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?64003-zen_mail-How-does-it-work

I have modified a php file in the below lines:

```
function sub_button() {

$process_button_string = zen_draw_getuserinfo_field('usercasenumber_', $_POST['u_case'])

}
return $process_button_string;
try {
zen_mail("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx@gmail.com","xxxxxxxx", $process_button_string, W_NAME, EMAIL_FROM);
} catch (Exception $e) {

}

  }
```

but still not receiving any email on completing doing submit on that page. everything else goes well. I am not very good with php and just added below part:

try {
    zen_mail("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx@gmail.com","xxxxxxxx", $process_button_string, W_NAME, EMAIL_FROM);
} catch (Exception $e) {

}

Am I doing something wrong? Please help

Comment: what errors are you getting, e.g., value of `$e`?

Comment: I am not getting any error, I click on the submit button and it goes to the next page as usual and everything goes fine but it does not send that mail

Comment: try adding: `echo '<pre>$e: '; print_r($e); echo '</pre>'; exit;` **after** `(Exception $e) {`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it! :)

```
function sub_button() {
$process_button_string = zen_draw_getuserinfo_field('usercasenumber_', $_POST['u_case']);

}
$msg = $_POST['u_case'];
try {
zen_mail("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx@gmail.com","xxxxxxxx", 
$msg, W_NAME, EMAIL_FROM);
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
return $process_button_string;
  }
```